# selenium - how to target a checkbox with a NAME and a VALUE

Tags: css, selenium, css-selectors, selenium-ide

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="small-4 columns text-right">
    <input type="radio" value="false" name="auto_policy[autos_attributes][0][parked_at_mailing_address]" autocomplete="smartystreets"></input>
    <div class="radio_button_label"></div>
    <input type="radio" value="true" name="auto_policy[autos_attributes][0][parked_at_mailing_address]" checked="checked" autocomplete="smartystreets" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></input>
    <div class="radio_button_label"></div>
</div>
```

How can I target the 'false' option, given that they have the same name?

I tried

```
css=a[name='auto_policy[add_violation]' value='false']
```

and

```
css=a[name='auto_policy[add_violation]', value='false']
```

but it was 'not found'

One option that works is to use

```
//input[@name='auto_policy[add_violation]'][2]
```

however I'd like to avoid the `[2]` which seems brittle and be able to use value='false' instead

Comment: Can you please add the complete html code snippet including the `a` tag having attribute `auto_policy[add_violation]` ?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following CSS selector (not how multiple conditions are combined):

```
css=input[name*=add_violation][value=false]
```

Where `*=` means "contains".

Alternatively, an XPath expression:

```
xpath=//input[contains(@name, "add_violation") and @value="false"]
```

Comment: Looked good but either seemed to be able to find the element even with a little fiddling.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant oops, it should've been `input`, not `a` - fixed :)